# mamp localhost not picking up wp-login

Tags: localhost, mac

looking for some help moving my wordpress site to a new Mac.

I've exported my database through phpmyadmin on the original device and imported it on the phpmyadmin on my new device. I've also copied the Wordpress folder over to htdocs in my mamp folder.

When I'm running mamp I can connect to my wordpress site through localhost:8888 on my new computer but I cannot reach wp-login to enable me to login or edit my site.

I have tried disabling all plugin's and theme's but still have the same issue

Could anyone help me get this up and running?

Thanks

Aa

Comment: Is the site URL set to :8888? (you can see that in `wp_options` table under `siteurl`) Usually it is no port/:80

Comment: So the siteurl is set to http://localhost:8888/wordpress. This address will show my website working on my browser too but I cannot access the wp-login or wp-admin extensions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your Wordpress site on the new device with a domain, such as wordpress.local instead of localhost:8888/wordpress, you may want to define a vhost configuration for MAMP first and add a local DNS record in your /etc/hosts file.

Once you've established the domain you want to use to access the site, you'll need to update it in the Wordpress database.

You can use one of these common methods to perform the update:

1. Manually perform a sql find & replace.
2. Use a tool like WP Migrate to export the database from legacy site to new site.
3. Use WP-CLI's search-replace command.

Finally, you'll want to make sure that you've copied the .htaccess file into the root of your Wordpress directory on the new instance (since it's a hidden file, it may have been overlooked).  Should you find after these steps your Wordpress site still doesn't load, it's worth checking to make sure your apache configuration allows for .htaccess overrides.